# How to resume download tasks (NSURLSessionDownloadTask) after restart app

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I add "download tasks" and kill app process.

After run app, get [manager downloadTasks]; and resume all.
But files not loaded in Documets Directory.

I use AFNetworking 2.0 ( https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking )

Full code - https://github.com/nullproduction/FileDownloader

```
//
//  DownloadsViewController.m
//

#import "DownloadsViewController.h"

@implementation DownloadsViewController

- (id)init
{
    [self printDocumentsPath];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"downloads"];

    manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
    NSArray *downloadTasks = [manager downloadTasks];

    if (downloadTasks.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"downloadTasks: %@", downloadTasks);
        // resume all
        for (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask in downloadTasks)
        {
            [downloadTask resume];
        }
    }

    return [super init];
}

- (void)addDownloadTask:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar500.exe"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request
    progress:nil
    destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
       NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
        return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[targetPath lastPathComponent]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];

    NSLog(@"%d", downloadTask.taskIdentifier);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"addDownloadTask" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addDownloadTask:)];
}

- (void)printDocumentsPath
{
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSLog(@"%@", documentsDirectoryPath);
}



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed, that the files are not present when looking in the documents directory in finder after the download finished. However, when accessing the file from the app, it will find it. The file finally appears in documents-dir after some time (within a minute). This could be a issue related to the simulator only..